# Maximal open set in which a subspace is dense

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A \subset X$, show that there is a maximal open set $B \subseteq X$ in which $A$ is dense.

I don't really know how to start, but this is what I tried:
Of course, $A$ is dense in $\bar{A}$ , but $\bar{A}$ is not necessarily open. $Int (\bar{A})$ is open by definition, and since $Int (\bar{A}) \subset A$ we get that every open subset $U$ of $Int (\bar{A})$ is an open subset of $\bar{A}$ as well and thus (I'm not sure of this implication) it's intersection with $A$ is none-empty.

So $Int (\bar{A})$ is an open set in which $A$ is dense, Now, suppose I'm correct, and this is the maximal set in which $A$ is dense, how do I show it?

Comment: This is false. There are some sets $A$ which are not dense in any open set.

Comment: @Crostul , I think that in that case, the answer is $\emptyset$ which is open

Comment: If $U$ is an open set, then "$A$ is dense in $U$" requires $A \subseteq U$. Now, let $X$ be the usual real line, $A = \Bbb{Z} \cup (0,1)$. There is no open set in which $A$ is dense, however $(0,1) \subseteq A$ is dense in the open set $(0,1)$. I think that "being dense in an open set" does not behave nicely, are you sure that you would say $A$ is dense inside the empty set?

Comment: I see. well, thank you!

Comment: @Crostul: It’s not common, and I think that it really stretches the language, but I have seen $A$ *is dense in* $B$ used to mean that $B\subseteq\operatorname{cl}A$, in which case the OP’s interpretation would be correct.

Answer (score 1):

I’m quite sure that $\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}A$ is the intended answer, though as **Crostul** points out in the comments, this is not always a superset of $A$ and requires a relatively uncommon interpretation of *dense in*, namely, that $A$ is dense in $B$ if and only if $\operatorname{cl}A\supseteq B$. Assuming that this is the definition that you’re supposed to use — the theorem is false if it is not — then clearly $\operatorname{cl}A$ is the largest set in which $A$ is dense, and $A$ is dense in all subsets of $\operatorname{cl}A$. The largest *open* set in which $A$ is dense is therefore the largest open subset of $\operatorname{cl}A$, which we know is $\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}A$, since for any set $S$, $\operatorname{int}S$ is the union of all open subsets of $S$.